# samsung s5 activity log

Tags: applications, samsung, history

I am suspecting that a friend of mine may have deleted an app I use for unknown reasons is there anyway I could see the phone activity log to check wet her the app was uninstalled and at what time

Comment: If you use it wouldn't you notice that it's missing?

Comment: I noticed it missing it was deleted what I want to know is how and at what time that's why I am asking about the phone's activity log

Answer (score 0):

No there is no activity log but if you go on the play store and view all apps you can see all the apps youve downloaded and it will tell you if they are installed or not. Let me know if this helped

Comment: No I don't want to know whether the app is installed or not I knew that it was uninstalled and I reinstalled it however what I really want to know is that if there exists an activity log where I could see what has happened to my phone at specific times for example it might show :"app name .. uninstalled 12:30 am 9/11/2014".got it?